# SQL server Order To with case and multiple columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have SQL query with the following `ORDER BY` statement:

```
ORDER BY SName, DateEnrolledTo desc
```

I need to change this to

```
ORDER BY
CASE WHEN @SortID='name' OR ISNULL(@SortID,'')=''
THEN SName, DateEnrolledTo desc END,
CASE WHEN @SortID ='Hroom' 
THEN Hroom, DateEnrolledTo desc END
```

The syntax for this is incorrect, can anybody tell me how to fix this? This only works if I only include 1 column. I couldn't find any questions that had this situation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As any expression [`CASE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx) evaluates to one value also after `THEN` yuo can specify one column (or any other [valid expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190286.aspx)):

```
ORDER BY
 CASE
  WHEN @SortID='name' OR ISNULL(@SortID,'')=''
   THEN SName
  WHEN @SortID ='Hroom' 
   THEN Hroom END,
 DateEnrolledTo desc
```

Answer (score 2):

Use your case statement to check all conditions and define which column will be used for the Ascending order condition.

Here is the `ORDER BY` clause you're looking for:

```
ORDER BY CASE
           WHEN @SortID = 'name'
               OR ISNULL(@SortID,'') = '' THEN SName
           WHEN @SortID = 'Hroom' THEN Hroom
         END, DateEnrolledTo DESC
```

Hope this will help you.